# Many to Many Composite Key mapping infinite loop

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Hibernate is getting into an infinite loop and hitting the DB until Stackoverflow. How do I resolve this, when I want setup bidirectional many-to-many in Hibernate?

These are DB Model classes:

**Account** - one side of the Many to Many relation

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "account_id")
    private Long accountId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "id.account", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<AccountAppuser> accountAppusers = new HashSet<AccountAppuser>(0);
    .. getters, setters, hashCode, equals
}
```

**Appuser** - the other side of the Many to Many relation

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "appuser")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Appuser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "appuser_id")
    private Long appuserId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "id.appuser", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<AccountAppuser> accountAppusers = new HashSet<AccountAppuser>(0);
    .. getters, setters, hashCode, equals
}
```

**AccountAppuser** - The Composite Key

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account_appuser")
@AssociationOverrides({ @AssociationOverride(name = "id.account", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "account_id") ), @AssociationOverride(name = "id.appuser", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "appuser_id") ) })
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AccountAppuser {
    @EmbeddedId
    private AccountAppuserId id;
    private String access;
    .. getters, setters, hashCode, equals
}
```

**AccountAppuserId** - the Composite Key Id bean

```
@Embeddable
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AccountAppuserId implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne
    private Account account;
    @ManyToOne
    private Appuser appuser;
    .. getters, setters, hashCode, equals
}
```

These are my tables and data in them
**account**

```
account_id
1
2
3
4
```

**appuser**

```
appuser_id
11
12
13
14
```

**account_appuser**

```
account_id  appuser_id
1       11
1       12
1       13
1       14
2       11
2       12
2       13
2       14
```

And here is the **DAO** code

```
    public class AccountRepo {

        @Transactional(readOnly = true)
        public List<Account> getAllAccounts(){
            return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Account.class).list();
        }
    }
```

The **output** I'm getting:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        this_.account_id as account_1_0_1_,
        accountapp2_.account_id as account_2_0_3_,
        accountapp2_.account_id as account_2_1_3_,
        accountapp2_.appuser_id as appuser_3_1_3_,
        accountapp2_.account_id as account_2_1_0_,
        accountapp2_.appuser_id as appuser_3_1_0_,
        accountapp2_.access as access1_1_0_ 
    from
        account this_ 
    left outer join
        account_appuser accountapp2_ 
            on this_.account_id=accountapp2_.account_id
Hibernate: 
    select
        account0_.account_id as account_1_0_0_,
        accountapp1_.account_id as account_2_0_1_,
        accountapp1_.account_id as account_2_1_1_,
        accountapp1_.appuser_id as appuser_3_1_1_,
        accountapp1_.account_id as account_2_1_2_,
        accountapp1_.appuser_id as appuser_3_1_2_,
        accountapp1_.access as access1_1_2_ 
    from
        account account0_ 
    left outer join
        account_appuser accountapp1_ 
            on account0_.account_id=accountapp1_.account_id 
    where
        account0_.account_id=?
```

The second query above goes on forever.

Comment: Are you sure it is infinite or just very long (with possible OOM error). With so many EAGER fields, if you log as `baseUser1` then it will load `baseRol`, then it will load **all** of the users in the `baseRol`, then **all** of the other roles those users have, then **all** of the additional users that appear in those roles... Each time a new user or role is loaded, a new query will be needed to at least ensure that such user or role does not mean loading additional roles or users. In short, a very bad idea, it would be way more sensible to keep relationships lazy and load all users and roles.

Comment: Can u plz add stacktrace as well?

Comment: @SJuan76
adding LAZY on `accountAppusers` field in `Account` and `Appuser` solved the issue. Also I had to add @Transactional on my testclass to make the session last longer. 
@Sumit
For some reason StackTrace was not printing when i run the test class - issue with my local eclipse setup I guess.